# Dialog manipulation

Tags: user-interface, interface, dialog, wolfram-mathematica

I want to create a dialog window, where the user can perform various tasks, and would like him to return from the dialog by clicking on the Cancel button with the mouse (i.e. not by hitting Enter). Therefore I do not want to use CreateDialog. However, by creating a less-specific dialog window via CreateWindow, all strings appear unformatted.

```
expr = Column[{
   Row@{"set variable to: ", InputField["value", String]},
   "Try to hit Enter in any of the dialogs: it closes #2 but not #1.",
   CancelButton[]
   }];

CreateWindow[DialogNotebook[expr], WindowSize -> All, WindowMargins -> {{100, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, WindowTitle -> "1. CreateWindow & DialogNotebook"];
CreateDialog[expr, WindowTitle -> "2. CreateDialog"];
```

[image: dialog windows]

Is there any clever way to have the looks of the second dialog window, but the button-behaviour of the first one? Of course, `expr` here is a simple example, but it can be quite complex in reality, thus it is no option to wrap every string into `Cell[string, "Text"]`, and every other expression into some obscure boxform.

Comment: The "Cancel" button is usually used for cancelling (ie disregarding) your input ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will stop your dialog window closing when Enter is pressed:

```
CreateDialog[expr, WindowTitle -> "2. CreateDialog", NotebookEventActions -> {}];
```

It overwrites the default dialog NotebookEventActions.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps using `TextCell`:

```
expr = Column[{Row@{TextCell@"set variable to: ", 
                    InputField["value", String]}, 
               TextCell@"Try to hit Enter in any of the dialogs: \
                         it closes #2 but not #1.", 
               CancelButton[]}];

CreateWindow[
 DialogNotebook[expr], WindowSize -> All, 
 WindowMargins -> {{100, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
 WindowTitle -> "1. CreateWindow & DialogNotebook"]
```

**Edit**

Use

```
 TextCell@Style[" ... blah blah ...", style_opt ]
```

for formatting.

Comment: I already tried this method, but it requires that every expression is wrapped either in a TextCell or in Style, which is a bit tedious when you have a complex dialog window. Also, as I stated above for ragfield's solution, one has to find out the default style of dialogs to reproduce, which is not a trivial task.

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
expr = Style[
   Column[{Row@{"set variable to: ", InputField["value", String]}, 
     "Try to hit Enter in any of the dialogs: it closes #2 but not \
#1.", CancelButton[]}], ShowStringCharacters -> False];
```

Comment: This is useful, I always forget about this option, thanks! However in this case I have to manually set the font style options to match the default style of other dialogs elements created with CreateDialog.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this, and other folks have posted two good ones, but in my opinion the easiest approach is to set the `BaseStyle` of the `Column` expression to match the base style of the dialog, and then use `CreateWindow`. The style in question is `"Panel"`, so this gets you the result you want:

```
expr = Column[{Row@{"set variable to: ", InputField["value", String]},
     "Try to hit Enter in any of the dialogs: it closes #2 but not #1.", 
     CancelButton[]}, BaseStyle -> "Panel"];

CreateWindow[DialogNotebook[expr], WindowSize -> All, 
  WindowMargins -> {{100, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
  WindowTitle -> "1. CreateWindow & DialogNotebook"];
```

Comment: Almost perfect solution, but no cigar: on my machine, the column appears with a white background in front of the gray background of the dialog window. Again, I have to manually set the correct GrayLevel, as not even Background -> None seems to work for the Column.